# Rewrite a function in locked env

Tags: r, pvclust

Using `pvclust::pvclust` , I got an error

> Error in solve.default(crossprod(X, X/vv)) :    Lapack routine dgesv:
>   system is exactly singular: U[2,2] = 0 Calls:  ...
>   pvclust.merge -> lapply -> FUN -> msfit -> solve -> solve.default
>   Execution halted

I don't want stop analysis even if `crossprod(X, X/vv)` be singular matrix, so I tried to insert an `if {...}` block in `pvclust::msfit` to check whether `crossprod(X, X/vv)` is singular or not by `matrixcalc::is.singular.matrix`, and if it is so, return `NA` and continue.

After saved *my.msfit.R* which contain `msfit` which incerted  `if(!is.singular.matrix(...)) {...}else{...}` in original `pvclust::msfit`,

> methods::insertSource('/myFuncDir/my.msfit.R',package="pvclust",functions='msfit')

But I got error below

> Error in assign(this, thisObj, envir = envwhere) : 
>     cannot change value of locked binding for 'msfit'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In methods::insertSource(filename, package = "pvclust", functions = "msfit",  :
>     cannot insert these (not found in source): "msfit"

Is there any solution? Should I request of the author of the `pvclust` package?

== Below added after posting ==

An accurate advice was given in comments to use try/catch syntax, but I don't think it will give me solution.

Concerning my poor English skill, I present a toy sample which tells the situation.

```
fun.a <- function(a1,a2,a3,a4){
  sum1 <- a1 + a2
  sum2 <- a2 + a3
  sum3 <- a3 + a4
  return(list(sum1,sum2,sum3))
 }

fun.a(1,2,3,'Char')
```

Because that the `sum3` will be an error, so `fun.a(1,2,3,'Char')` returns `error`.

But, I want to return

> List [sum1, sum2, NaN]

If I use `tryCatch(...,error=expr)`, sum1 to sum3(actually, `solve(...)`in `pvclust::msfit`) should be wrapped.
But, `fun.a`(`msfit`) is inner function of locked package(`pvclust`).

Comment: Is this somethings you can wrap in a try/catch block to recover from the error? Why must you change the source of function?

Comment: If you must change the source, pull the package source off CRAN, modify the code there, and then rebuild and reinstall package.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for advice. I had never used error handling syntax, so googled and tried to run it in my code. But it did not give solution. I edited my question to update the situation.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you. I've never manipulated packages, so it is challenging. I will try to do, and update my question.